# Returning wchar_t* from C++/CLI to native

Tags: visual-c++, memory-management, c++-cli

Let's say we have a pure virtual C++ class:

```
class INativeInterface {
public:
    virtual ~INativeInterface () {};
    virtual LPCWSTR GetString () = 0;
};
```

and then we need to provide an implementation of this interface in C++/CLI:

```
class HalfManagedImplementation : public INativeInterface {
public:
    virtual LPCWSTR GetString () override {
        // need to return wchar_t const * pointer which points to the 
        // data of our managedData string
        // pin_ptr is not suitable as it will go out of scope
        // what other options do we have here?
        // perhaps copying managed string contents to unmanaged heap?
        wchar_t * unmanagedString = new wchar_t [managedData->Length + 1];
        pin_ptr<const wchar_t> pinnedString = PtrToStringChars (managedData);
        wcscpy_s (unmanagedString, managedData->Length + 1, pinnedString);
        return unmanagedString;
    }
private:
    String^ managedData;
    void SetString (String^ param){
        // do something in .net
        managedData = param;
    }
};
```

My main questions are:

1. Can I allocate a native string on CRT heap and return a pointer to it to the native C++ code as I did above given that the memory allocated by managed code will be de-allocated by the native code?
   An example of usage:

   `LPCWSTR data = cppCliObject->GetString ();
   // do stuff with returned data or persist it by copying it somewhere else
   delete[] data;`
2. Is the first point valid when native C++ code is in a different dll than C++/CLI one?
3. Are there any other alternatives or best practices when returning wchar_t data to native C++?

Comment: It is a bad idea.  Use int GetString(wchar_t buffer, size_t buffersize) instead so that the caller can pass his own buffer.  Or return BSTR and use SysAllocString() to create it so it is crystal that the caller has to destroy it again.  Or return std::wstring last.

Comment: Thanks, Hans. Initially I thought of returning std::wstring but hesitated because the string is latter used as wchar_t. I guess returning a std::wstring is more a C++ way while passing a buffer - more C. I'll stick to C++.

Comment: The conversion is more simple using marshal_as. std::wstring result = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::wstring>(managedString); You will have to add the following line into your code #include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>